# falta el archivo `node-env-file`

Tags: javascript

Intento lanzar un bot botkit creado con javascript que me ha dado un amigo. Sin embargo al lanzarlo parece que me falta un archivo `node-env-file`.

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 804E-C690

 Directory of C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app

04/05/2019  03:16 PM    <DIR>          .
04/05/2019  03:16 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/03/2019  05:15 PM    <DIR>          .config
04/03/2019  05:14 PM    <DIR>          .data
04/05/2019  03:16 PM             6,148 .DS_Store
01/28/2019  04:35 PM             3,537 .env
04/03/2019  05:15 PM    <DIR>          .git
11/01/2018  05:38 PM                55 .gitignore
11/01/2018  05:38 PM             4,931 .glitch-assets
11/01/2018  06:42 AM                14 .node-gyp
03/19/2018  04:15 PM                67 .node_repl_history
05/07/2018  09:39 AM             3,463 .viminfo
11/01/2018  05:38 PM               657 app.json
01/19/2019  12:43 PM             6,454 bot.js
04/03/2019  05:15 PM    <DIR>          build
04/03/2019  05:16 PM    <DIR>          components
04/03/2019  05:16 PM    <DIR>          configs
04/03/2019  05:16 PM    <DIR>          docs
11/01/2018  05:38 PM             1,130 glitch_readme.md
04/03/2019  05:14 PM                 0 Icon_
11/01/2018  05:38 PM             1,935 package.json
04/03/2019  05:15 PM    <DIR>          path_to_json_database
04/03/2019  05:14 PM    <DIR>          public
11/01/2018  05:38 PM             7,176 readme.md
04/03/2019  05:16 PM    <DIR>          scripts
11/14/2018  01:15 AM           236,792 shrinkwrap.yaml
04/03/2019  05:16 PM    <DIR>          skills
04/03/2019  05:16 PM    <DIR>          src
11/01/2018  05:38 PM           275,781 yarn.lock
              15 File(s)        548,140 bytes
              14 Dir(s)  789,317,816,320 bytes free

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app>node .
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-env-file'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app\bot.js:20:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Soy nuevo en javascript pero me recuerda los entornos de python y sé que a veces tenemos un archivo `requirements.txt`. ¿Qué puedo hacer para deshacerse de este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas descargar node https://nodejs.org/es/

O ejecutar en la consola de comandos `npm install -g` para instalar la ultima versión si ya lo tuvieras instalado.

Si sigue fallando, prueba a instalar el archivo que te falta de la siguiente manera `npm install node-env-file` (en el directorio del proyecto)

Comment: Y no existe un equivalente a `pip install -r requirements.txt` ?

Comment: pip es un sistema de gestión de paquetes utilizado para instalar y administrar paquetes de software escritos en Python. Para javascript el equivalente es node y la sintaxis es `npm install` que ya te genera las dependencias que necesite tu aplicación y que están en el fichero package.json y el directorio node_modules, claro que para ello necesitas tener node instalado como te pongo justo encima.